# Continuity of a rational function

Tags: real-analysis

This is a simple question. Given a real valued rational function
$$
f (x) = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\quad x\in\mathbf R^N,
$$
this is called regular on a point if the denominator $q$ does not vanish there. We know that

1. $f$ is regular on an open convex set $D$ and
2. for a point $x_0$ on the boundary $\partial D$ of $D$ the limits of $f$ along any ray coming from $\partial D$ upon $x_0$ exists and do not depend on the ray. More precisely: for any $x_1$ from $D$ the limit $tx_1 + (1 - t)x_0$ as $t$ tends to $0$ exists and is independent of $x_1$.

**Question**: is $f$ regular at $x_0$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the denominator vanishes, the function is not just irregular, it is undef ined.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker ... Irregular points could possibly have $p(x_0)=q(x_0)=0$, so Vestic asks if this could happen under conditions (i) and (ii).

Comment: @GeraldEdgar technically under the definition given, if $q(x_0) = 0$ then $f$ is not regular at $x_0$.

Comment: @user44191 : good point.  It should be replaced by "can be made regular".

Answer (score 4):

If $f(x,y)=\frac{y-x^2}{y+x^2}$ and $D$ is any set above the parabola $y=x^2$, then it seems to me that the limit along any ray will always be $1$.

Comment: Thanks to a fine example, which indicates how to strengthen the conditions to obtain a positive  answer. Indeed,

Comment: Thanks very much to professor Katz for the illuminating example.

Comment: sorry for my first comment (mistake). In fact there is no possibility to extend by mere continuity either..